# Memory management : release viewcontroller object after adding to NSMutableArray

Tags: iphone, memory-management, analyzer

I have a memory leak with below code. If I use `[sub release];`after adding sub to NSmutableArray(subViewController),  Analyzer says *"Inconrrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller"*, when i remove `[sub release]` then it says *"Potential leak of an object allocated on xx line"*

```
for (int i=0; i<[self.data count]; i++) {

   SubCategoryViewController *sub =[[SubCategoryViewController alloc] 
           initwithServiceUrl:urlString andHeaderValue: 
          ((PMCategory *)[self.data objectAtIndex:i]).categoryName];

   [[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate].viewController.subViewControllers addObject:sub];
   [sub release];


}
```

Alson if I use autorelease Warning becomes *"Object sent -autorelease too many times"*

```
SubCategoryViewController *sub =[[[SubCategoryViewController alloc] 
           initwithServiceUrl:urlString andHeaderValue: 
          ((PMCategory *)[self.data objectAtIndex:i]).categoryName]autorelease];
```

Added from comment: 
SubCategoryViewController Init method:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *data;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *headerText;
@synthesize data = _data;
@synthesize headerText=_headerText;
```

...

```
self = [super init];
if (self) {
    self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
    self.headerText =headerValue;
    self.serviceURL =serviceU;
    self.firstLoad = YES;
}
return self;
```

Comment: What does your custom init method look like (or at least show the return statement)

Comment: SubCategoryViewController Init method: self = [super init];
    
    if (self) {
        self.data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init] ;
        
        self.headerText =headerValue;
        self.serviceURL =serviceU;
       
        self.firstLoad = YES;
    }
    return  self;

Comment: Show the @property statement for data. (You can edit your question I think).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because you haven't followed proper naming convention of Objective c. Whenever you are writing any initialization function namingConvention  is something like

```
-(id) initFirstWordSecondWord{
}
```

means make first letter after init Capital.

So change your `initwithServiceUrl` to `initWithServiceUrl` and your problem will be solved.
cheer up!!!

Answer (score 0):

If `data` is a property with the `retain` attribute then it is over retained, once by:

```
[[NSMutableArray alloc] init]
```

and once by the property setter.

Change it to use the class convenience method that returns an autoreleased `NSMutableArray`:

```
self.data = [NSMutableArray array];
```

Additionally the for loop can be written more clearly with fast enumeration:

```
for (PMCategory *category in self.data) {
    SubCategoryViewController *sub =[[SubCategoryViewController alloc] 
        initwithServiceUrl:urlString
        andHeaderValue:category.categoryName];
```